# Adding padding is adding unwanted width to element, fix? CSS

Tags: html, css, padding

All my searches to find an answer have failed, so here goes. I'm trying to add bottom padding to a button that is wrapped inside of a div, and I want to move the button up closer to the top. However, when padding is added it just stretches the buttons width & height. Sorry if this is something really simple, i'm faily new to coding!

```
.div {
background-image: url('images/banner.png');
width: 920px;   
height: 280px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

```
.button {
width: 226px;
height: 57px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px; /* border radius */
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box; /* prevents bg color from leaking outside the border */
background-color: #f1efea; /* layer fill content */
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.77), inset 0 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.31); /* drop shadow and inner shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.77), inset 0 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.31); /* drop shadow and inner shadow */
box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.77), inset 0 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.31); /* drop shadow and inner shadow */
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); /* gradient overlay */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ec9531 0.5%, #efa755 99.5%); /* gradient overlay */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ec9531 0.5%, #efa755 99.5%); /* gradient overlay */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ec9531 0.5%, #efa755 99.5%); /* gradient overlay */
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #ec9531 0.5%, #efa755 99.5%); /* gradient overlay */
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the box model for that element.

```
.button {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This ensures that the amount of padding is not added to the overal width or height and the width and height remain the size you specified whatever the padding — or border — value.

Want to know more read this post: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do it:

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px; /* will result in .button moving 5px 'up' from where it is */
}
```

Or you could adjust the margin:

```
.button {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Note, however, that adjusting the margin will affect the position of any elements that are placed relative to .button, where as specifying the 'top' value will not.  Remember to declare 'position: relative;' first if using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your respective class, it will help you.

```
div {
  position: relative;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
}
```